# Silverlight KeyDowns from Javascript

Tags: silverlight, events

There is any way to listen for the Silverlight plugin pressed keys from the HTML page onKeyDown event? I can have multiple .xap loaded in my HTML and all the .xaps should handle same shortcut keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a proxy via a `ScriptableType`, unfortunately you have to do this in all your Silverlight applications.

```
[ScriptableType]
public class KeyPressProxy
{
    public KeyPressProxy()
    {
        App.Current.RootVisual.KeyDown += (s, e) => KeyDown(s, e);
    }

    [ScriptableMember]
    public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown = delegate { };
}
```

Then you have to register the object, but be sure you do this after the RootVisual has been created:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    this.RootVisual = new MainPage();

    var proxy = new KeyPressProxy();
    HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("KeyPressProxy", proxy);
}
```

Finally you can add a handler in your javascript:

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost">
    <object id="silverlightApp1" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
        <param name="onLoad" value="onPluginLoaded" />
        <!-- ... -->
    </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onPluginLoaded() {
        document.getElementById('silverlightApp1').content.KeyPressProxy.KeyDown = function (s, e) {
            alert('pressed');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Updated to use onPluginLoaded instead.